# Java's final vs. C++'s const

Tags: java, c++, constants, final

The [Java for C++ programmers tutorial](http://triton.towson.edu/~mzimand/os/Lect2-java-tutorial.html#access) says that (highlight is my own):

> The keyword final is **roughly**
>   equivalent to const in C++

What does "roughly" mean in this context? Aren't they *exactly* the same?

What are the differences, if any?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

In C++ marking a member function `const` means it may be called on `const` instances. Java does not have an equivalent to this. E.g.:

```
class Foo {
public:
   void bar();
   void foo() const;
};

void test(const Foo& i) {
   i.foo(); //fine
   i.bar(); //error
}
```

---

Values can be assigned, once, later in Java only e.g.:

```
public class Foo {
   void bar() {
     final int a;
     a = 10;
   }
}
```

is legal in Java, but not C++ whereas:

```
public class Foo {
   void bar() {
     final int a;
     a = 10;
     a = 11; // Not legal, even in Java: a has already been assigned a value.
   }
}
```

---

In both Java and C++ member variables may be `final`/`const` respectively. These need to be given a value by the time an instance of the class is finished being constructed.

In Java they must be set before the constructor has finished, this can be achieved in one of two ways:

```
public class Foo {
   private final int a;
   private final int b = 11;
   public Foo() {
      a = 10;
   }
}
```

In C++ you will need to use initialisation lists to give `const` members a value:

```
class Foo {
   const int a;
public:
   Foo() : a(10) {
      // Assignment here with = would not be legal
   }
};
```

---

In Java final can be used to mark things as non-overridable. C++ (pre-C++11) does not do this. E.g.:

```
public class Bar {
   public final void foo() {
   }
}

public class Error extends Bar {
   // Error in java, can't override
   public void foo() {
   }
}
```

But in C++:

```
class Bar {
public:
   virtual void foo() const {
   }
};

class Error: public Bar {
public:
   // Fine in C++
   virtual void foo() const {
   }
};
```

this is fine, because the semantics of marking a member function `const` are different. (You could also *overload* by only having the `const` on one of the member functions. (Note also that C++11 allows member functions to be marked final, see the C++11 update section)

---

### C++11 update:

C++11 does in fact allow you to mark both classes and member functions as `final`, with identical semantics to the same feature in Java, for example in Java:

```
public class Bar {
   public final void foo() {
   }
}

public class Error extends Bar {
   // Error in java, can't override
   public void foo() {
   }
}
```

Can now be exactly written in C++11 as:

```
class Bar {
public:
  virtual void foo() final;
};

class Error : public Bar {
public:
  virtual void foo() final;
};
```

I had to compile this example with a pre-release of G++ 4.7. Note that this does not replace `const` in this case, but rather augments it, providing the Java-like behaviour that wasn't seen with the closest equivalent C++ keyword. So if you wanted a member function to be both `final` and `const` you would do:

```
class Bar {
public:
  virtual void foo() const final;
};
```

(The order of `const` and `final` here is required).

Previously there wasn't a direct equivalent of `const` member functions although making functions non-`virtual` would be a potential option albeit without causing an error at compile time.

Likewise the Java:

```
public final class Bar {
}

public class Error extends Bar {
}
```

becomes in C++11:

```
class Bar final {
};

class Error : public Bar {
};
```

(Previously `private` constructors was probably the closest you could get to this in C++)

Interestingly, in order to maintain backwards compatibility with pre-C++11 code `final` *isn't* a keyword in the usual way. (Take the trivial, legal C++98 example `struct final;` to see why making it a keyword would break code)

Comment: You should make those methods virtual; otherwise, you are really not doing the same thing

Comment: In your last example, you what you have is legal, but it's worth mentioning that `final int a; a = 10; a = 11;` is not (that being the purpose of `final` as a variable modifier.) Also, final members a class can only be set at declaration time, or once in a constructor.

Comment: Note that C++0x adds the `final` member function decorator for this exact purpose. VC++ 2005, 2008, and 2010 already have this implemented, using the contextual keyword `sealed` rather than `final`.

Comment: @ildjarn -that's interesting to know and yet another relatively small C++0x change that I wasn't aware of! I'll probably add a small comment somewhere in the text indicating that this is changing with C++0x.

Comment: Apparently people still do still s/const/final/g in codebases with  [finalructor](http://www.irrlicht3d.org/pivot/entry.php?id=1331) as the result!

Comment: Also the presence or absence of the *virtual* keyword in an overriding derived class member function is completely optional and has no effect.

Answer (score 37):

A `const` object can only call `const` methods, and is generally considered immutable.

```
const Person* person = myself;
person = otherPerson; //Valid... unless we declared it const Person* const!
person->setAge(20); //Invalid, assuming setAge isn't a const method (it shouldn't be)
```

A `final` object cannot be set to a new object, but it is not immutable - there is nothing stopping someone from calling any `set` methods.

```
final Person person = myself;
person = otherPerson; //Invalid
person.setAge(20); //Valid!
```

Java has no inherent way of declaring objects immutable; you need to design the class as immutable yourself.

When the variable is a primitive type, `final`/`const` work the same.

```
const int a = 10; //C++
final int a = 10; //Java
a = 11; //Invalid in both languages
```

Comment: This is a great answer, too (like many others here). Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer. :)

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 31):

In Java the final keyword can be used for four things:

- on a class or method to seal it (no subclasses / overriding allowed)
- on a member variable to declare that is it can be set exactly once (I think this is what you are talking about)
- on a variable declared in a method, to make sure that it can be set exactly once
- on a method parameter, to declare that it cannot be modified within the method

One important thing is: 
A Java final member variable **must** be set exactly once! For example, in a constructor, field declaration, or intializer. (But you cannot set a final member variable in a method).

Another consequence of making a member variable final relates to the memory model, which is important if you work in a threaded environment.

Comment: What do you mean by say 'memory model'? I don't get it.

Comment: @Tony: Java Language Specification, Chapter 17.4. Memory Model - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html -- googles first hit

Answer (score 14):

Java final is equivalent to C++ const on primitive value types.

With Java reference types, the final keyword is equivalent to a const pointer... i.e.

```
//java
final int finalInt = 5;
final MyObject finalReference = new MyObject();

//C++
const int constInt = 5;
MyObject * const constPointer = new MyObject();
```

Comment: "the final keyword is equivalent to a const pointer" well said

Answer (score 9):

Java's `final` works only on primitive types and references, never on object instances themselves where the const keyword works on anything.

Compare `const list<int> melist;` with `final List<Integer> melist;` the first makes it impossible to modify the list, while the latter only stops you from assigning a new list to `melist`.

Answer (score 8):

You have some great answers here already, but one point that seemed worth adding: `const` in C++ is commonly used to prevent other parts of the program changing the state of objects. As has been pointed out, `final` in java can't do this (except for primitives) - it just prevents the *reference* from being changed to a different object. But if you are using a `Collection`, you can prevent changes to your objects by using the static method

```
 Collection.unmodifiableCollection( myCollection )
```

This returns a `Collection` reference that gives read-access to the elements, but throws an exception if modifications are attempted, making it a bit like `const` in C++

Answer (score 3):

Aside from having certain and [subtle multi-threading properties](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml), variables declared *`final`* don't need to be initialized on declaration!

i.e. This is valid in Java:

```
// declare the variable
final int foo;

{
    // do something...

    // and then initialize the variable
    foo = ...;
}
```

This would not be valid if written with C++'s *`const`*.

Answer (score 2):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Difference_from_the_C.2B.2B_.22const.22_type_qualifier):

- In C++, a const field is not only protected from being reassigned, but there is the additional limitation that only const methods can be called on it and it can only be passed as the const argument of other methods.
- Non-static inner classes can freely access any field of the enclosing class, final or not.

Comment: The word 'reassigned' does not appear in the current version of that page, and neither does anything resembling your second point, which is either incorrect or irrelevant, depending on what you mean by 'access'. 'Non-static inner' is double-talk. Wikipedia is not a normative reference for either C++ or Java.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing it says "roughly" because the meaning of `const` in C++ gets complicated when you talk about pointers, i.e. constant pointers vs. pointers to constant objects.  Since there are no "explicit" pointers in Java, `final` does not have these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain what I understood with an example of switch/case statement.

The values in each case statement must be compile-time constant values of the same data type as the switch value.

declare something like below (either in your method as local instances, or in your class as static variable(add static to it then), or an instance variable.

```
final String color1 = "Red";
```

and

```
static final String color2 = "Green";

switch (myColor) { // myColor is of data type String
    case color1:
    //do something here with Red
    break;
    case color2:
    //do something with Green
    break;
}
```

This code will not compile, if `color1` is a class/instance variable and not a local variable.
This will compile if `color1` is defined as static final (then it becomes static final variable).

When it does not compile, you will get the following error

```
error: constant string expression required
```

Answer (score -7):

keyword "const" mean that your variable is saved in ROM (with Microprocessor). in computer, your variable is saved in RAM area for Assembly code (read only RAM). it means that your variable is not in the  writeable RAM include: static memory, stack memory and heap memory.

keyword "final" mean that your variable is saved in writeable RAM, but you notice to compiler that your variable is only change only one time.

```
//in java language you can use:
static final int i =10;
i =11; //error is showed here by compiler

//the same in C++ the same as follows
int i =10;
const int &iFinal = i;

iFinal = 11; //error is showed here by compiler the same as above
```

I think, "const" is bad in performance, so Java does not use it.