# How to get an element of a non-final ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, final

I've a class Persona with:

```
String name;
Int age;
```

And I have an `ArrayList<Persona>`, then

I fill the ArrayList with a for loop which `add(new Persona(name,age))` with a JSON parse data (this JSON parsing is from a PHP request to a MySQL DB which returns a random number of "Persona's").

When the loop finish, I want to get one of this Persona's, but Eclipse IDE said to me that to use `get(i)` I have to declare the ArrayList like `final`, and if I do that, I can't fill it.

This is the code:

```
ArrayList<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<Persona>();
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

try {
    personas = json.getJSONArray(TAG);
    for(int i = 0; i < putas.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = personas.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        Int age = c.getString(TAG_AGE);
        personas.add(new Persona(name, age));
} catch (...) {
    ...
}

int i = 4;
Persona p = personas.get(i);
```

With this code, IDE show me an error and "offers" me to add the "final" modifier to the ArrayList, but it's absurd.

PD: The problem is with an Android application, but I think that it's a Java problem.

Comment: Are you sure that's the whole code? And why is "final" absurd?

Comment: Is Eclipse *demanding* you use `final`, or only suggesting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`final` is not the same as C++ `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971286/javas-final-vs-cs-const). Declaring `personas` to be a `final` reference does not prevent you altering the object that reference refers to.

Answer (score 0):

try initialising the array List in the try block...

```
 ArrayList<Persona> personas;
 JSONParser jParser;
 JSONObject json;
 try
 {
   personas = new ArrayList<Persona>();
   jParser = new JSONParser();
   json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

   // rest of the code
 }
 catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason that it won't compile unless you make it `final` there. You must be missing something out.

Either way, the `final` keyword simply means that you can't assign something to that field any more, not that you can't call its methods.

You're right in that, if you made `personas` `final` then your code as it stands won't work, because `personas = json.getJSONArray(TAG)` would not be allowed.

Since you're getting a complaint about being non-final when compiling, I'm assuming that you actually have some code after this, which uses `personas`. If you're trying to use that inside something like this:

`Runnable r = new Runnable() { public void run() { personas.get(0); } };`

Which you might be doing for a `View` listener or something.

That, would require you to make it final. The easiest solution to that would be just to make another local variable, and have that one be final.

`final ArrayList<Persona> finalPersonas = personas`

Comment: Thanks. It was easy to solve. I made it final. I thought that final was like a const, but it isn't, this explains my doubts, thanks.