# understanding a final static use on a map field of a class

Tags: java, encapsulation, final, static-members

I am c++ developer and trying to familiarize with Core Java concepts.
i found this confusing as to my final static is something it cannot be changed after the object is constructed. (correct me if i am wrong)

I came across the below implementation which i found confusing as it seems to allow value getting added into Map even when it is final static

```
public class MockUserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private static final Map<String, User> userMap = new HashMap<String, User>();

    public static void addUserToCache(int userId, String userName) {
        if (!userMap.containsKey(userName)) {
            userMap.put(userName, new User(userId, userName));
        }
    } 
}
```

Can someone try to explain me what exactly the static final here is meant to

Comment: Okay it makes more sense to explain why rather blindly saying not useful. Even if it is stupid question i am trying to understand here.

Comment: Have you tried looking it up?

Comment: yes :). Actually this is something confuses me. How can the user have an option to add information into Map. Rather if it is just static it would make sense. Trying to see if any online reference can be provided as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think of `Map` as a data structure. Think of it as any other class that has methods, for example `put(..)`. Are you saying that if you had

```
public class Foo {
    public void bar() {}
}
```

you shouldn't be able to call `bar()` on

```
final Foo foo = new Foo();
```

simply because it's `final`? What use would it have then?

The `final` keyword only prevents a variable from being reassigned, not what methods can be called or what fields can be accessed. [It has a different meaning when used on on methods and classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-final-keyword-works)

As for `static`, read:

[What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

All objects in java are references. final keyword means that the reference is final, but the object itself can be mutable. Look at [Java's final vs. C++'s const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971286/javas-final-vs-cs-const) .

Static keyword means that there is just single instance shared for all objects.

Answer (score 0):

`static` in Java in general means static context, something corresponding to classes. In this case static field can be seen a field of a class. Static fields can also be seen as global variables.

`final` is very similar to `const` in C++, meaning that the reference or value can not be re-assigned.

When used together they mean a constant reference or values having global visibility.

You might also want to read [JLS §8.3.1 Field Modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1).

Comment: yes i found the explanation trying to give an analogy with const pointer in c++ where we cannot change the pointer what it points to.