# Declaring A Trait With A Variable Named Wait Gives Override Compiler Error

Tags: java, scala

Given the following trait:

```scala
trait Foo {

  final val wait = "wait"

}
```

on compilation it emits the following override compiler error:

```scala
Value 'wait' cannot override final member
```

Declaring a variable inside a trait as above seems to clash with the following Java method in the `Object` class:

```java
    public final void wait() throws InterruptedException {
        this.wait(0L);
    }
```

Is this a bug or desired behaviour?

Comment: Likely desired behaviour, given that java.lang.Object has a number of methods, including wait: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait() . As a side-note, the decision to include so many methods in `Object` that most/all classes are subtypes of and inherit from might have been a mistake (though hindsight is 20/20). Especially `wait`, `notify` and `notifyAll`, since those are concurrency-specific and part of Java's support for monitors, and it gives some drawbacks to have them on all classes that inherits from `Object`.

Comment: that's correct you can't change the value of a final val right? what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25417645/1319284) you see that a `val` field actually also creates a getter method with the name of the field - in your case `wait()`. Since that clashes with the final `wait()` method on `Object`, that is indeed expected.

Answer (score 2):

`wait` is a `final` method defined in `Object` on JVM. Any other object extends `java.lang.Object`, so you cannot override/define methods that are `final` in it.

This is expected, otherwise you would end up with a weird behavior if you tried to use `wait` and `notify` in Java code where object came from part of the code written in Scala. Actually, Scala tries to hold all contracts that Java defined to be on a safe side of things.