# Java final String, C++ equivalent. Is my understanding correct?

Tags: java, c++, string

So I stumbled upon the following piece of Java code :

```
final String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
```

I have read in several other StackOverFlow questions that the String class is actually immutable. So I asked myself the following thing, why is it the String declared final?

I am not very good with C++, but in order to understand what happens behind the scenes(in Java) I decided to see what would be the equivalent in C++.

If my understanding is correct  making the String final in Java is equivalent in making a pointer in C++ being const, that is what the pointer variable points to cannot be changed. The limitation in Java is that you can change only the constness of the pointer to that String, but the chuck of memory the pointer points to is immutable.

So my question is am I correct or I am missing something else?

Comment: [Java's `final` is close-ish to C++'s `const`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971286/javas-final-vs-cs-const)

Comment: It cannot be assigned to after initialisation. So unmodifiable constants can use `public static final`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we say that Java String(s) are immutable, it is because a String object cannot be modified once created. Instead, you *must* create (and assign a reference to) a new String when you want to modify a String reference. When you mark a String variable as `final` you are additionally making the reference immutable.

Comment: What are the implications of making the reference immutable too?

Comment: @Ogen You can't assign a new String object to the String reference either (when it's final). That's it.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in your assumption.  String is immutable but without the final declaration the pointer can't be changed.  So if you want to "change" the String variable you can do so but it will not actually change the object it will create a new object and point the pointer to the new object.  Adding final makes it so you cannot do this it won't let you change the pointer reference and the String object that it points to is immutable so you cannot change a final String.

Answer (score 0):

Java differs in a number of ways.

In Java you can never alter a `String`'s contents after creation - it is **immutable**. Also the Java reference is essentially equivalent to a C++ pointer. But in C++ you **can** change the contents of a `std::string` unless it is declared `const`.

**Putting that together:**

```
String s = "stuff"; // Java
const std::string* s = new std::string("stuff"); // C++
```

Now making a Java reference `final` in Java means you can not change the reference to point to a different `String`. That is equivalent to making the pointer const in C++:

```
final String s = "stuff"; // Java
const std::string* const s = new std::string("stuff"); // C++
```

Also Jave manages memory automatically for its `String`s. This can be roughly approximated in C++.

**Like this:**

```
String s = "stuff"; // Java
std::shared_ptr<const std::string> s =
    std::make_shared<const std::string>("stuff"); // C++
```

and

```
final String s = "stuff"; // Java
const std::shared_ptr<const std::string> s =
    std::make_shared<const std::string>("stuff"); // C++
```